# Казахоязычная или казахскоязычная

Tags: словообразование

Казахоязычная или казахскоязычная и почему?

Answer (score 8):

Ни то, ни другое слово грамматике не противоречит: *казахскоязычный* образовано соединением основ слов *казахский* и *язык*, *казахоязычный* — основ *казах* и *язык* (т. е. *язык казахов*).

Если посмотреть на то, как образуются подобные составные прилагательные для других языков и семей языков, то видно, что предпочтение ожидаемо отдается более короткому варианту без суффикса *-ск-*: *англоязычный*, *арабоязычный*, *германоязычный*, *грекоязычный*, *ивритоязычный*, *ираноязычный*, *испаноязычный*, *италоязычный*, *тюркоязычный*, *украиноязычный*, *финноязычный*, *японоязычный* и т. п.

Примеры обратного тоже существуют. Первым приходит в голову, разумеется, *русскоязычный*; и он легко об’ясним — мы могли бы сказать **русоязычный* в том случае, если бы могли сказать *язык руси* (*русь* как собирательное) или *язык русов*, но так мы не говорим¹.

*Немецкоязычный*, а не *[немоязычный](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%22&hl=en)*; *польскоязычный*, а не **полеязычный*; *литовскоязычный*, а не **литоязычный* — вероятно, по сходной причине; нельзя также не отметить долю оксюморона в слове *немоязычный*. *Турецкоязычный* — вероятно, для размежевания с вышеупомянутым словом *тюркоязычный*, что относится ко всей тюрской языковой семье.

---

<sup>¹ См. также вопрос [«Why Russians use adjective when speaking about their nation and nouns for the rest of the world?»](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/7094/why-russians-use-adjective-when-speaking-about-their-nation-and-nouns-for-the-re)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Google search results:

- "казахоязычная" - 14 000 results;
- "казахскоязычная" - 10 100 results.

Apparently, there is no obvious preference.